# Why does the string passed to my method change to Typeof undefined after the first loop after initially being Typeof string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having trouble finding out why this occurs and what I can do in order to keep the Typeof as a string so that the method can complete

So far i have tried looking elsewhere as to why this might be happening but have been unable to find anything

```
const headingUpper = "Hello";
const speed = 50; // speed milleseconds
let count = 0;
let printedText;

typeEffect(headingUpper, "headingUpper");

function typeEffect(printedText, target) {
    if ((typeof printedText) === ("string")) {
        if (count < printedText.length) {
            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML += printedText.charAt(count);
            count++;
            setTimeout(typeEffect, speed);
            //console.log(typeof printedText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You told settimeout what function to call, but not how to call it. Please take a look at the function and understand how to call with parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `setTimeout` calls `typeEffect`, no arguments are being passed with your current code.

Either use an anonymous function that calls `typeEffect` with the same arguments

```js
setTimeout(() => typeEffect(printedText, target), speed);
```

Or pass the arguments as further arguments to `setTimeout`

```js
setTimeout(typeEffect, speed, printedText, target);
```